# How to see the typescript version is used in current deno version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deno

I tried with `deno -V`, it gives only deno's version and does not include typescript version.

```
$deno -V
deno 1.0.0-rc2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `--version` with the latest versions binary

```
$ deno --version
```

**OR Use deno shell**

```
$ deno
> Deno.version

Deno.version
{ deno: "1.0.0", v8: "8.4.300", typescript: "3.9.2" }
```

**Or using `eval` command**

```
$ deno eval "console.log(Deno.version)"
// OR
$ deno eval "console.log(Deno.version.typescript)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Typing `deno --version` gives you full informations

```sh
$ deno --version
deno 1.0.0
v8 8.4.300
typescript 3.9.2
```

Answer (score 1):

**01.** `deno --version` will gives you typescript version, deno version and
   v8 version

```
$ deno --version
deno 1.0.0
v8 8.4.300
typescript 3.9.2
```

**02.** By using deno shell and providing `Deno.version.typescript` will gives typescript version directly.

```
$ deno
> Deno.version.typescript
3.9.2
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

At the moment of writing the answer, the typescript is bundled in Deno as a Git submodule, which you can find [here on GitHub](https://github.com/denoland/deno/tree/master/deno_typescript), which has a revision of [551f0dd9a1b57ecd527a665b0af7fc98cd107af6](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/551f0dd9a1b57ecd527a665b0af7fc98cd107af6), which in turn corresponds to version 3.9.2.

Although, the question about printing the TypeScript version from deno CLI is a courtesy of Deno developers.

Comment: u can use `console.log(Deno.version)`